# Git clone from windows

Tags: linux, git, vmware

I am using `windows 8.1` as `host os` and `Ubuntu Linux` in `vmware guest`.I have created `git repository` in Linux and trying to clone it on windows using `tortoise git`. I am using my home's Wi-Fi connection but it is detected as `eth0` not as `wlan0`. I don't know why. If I delete that wired connection in guest Linux then it network connectivity not working.I have configured network connectivity as `bridged`.

Comment: Can you ping the Linux machine? This is not a git problem, it's a network problem.

Comment: If you want easy communication with your VM from the outside, set the network interface to "Bridged"

Comment: yes I have set network mode to bridged but still getting the same problem.